# fontface Android?

Tags: android, css, font-face

Is it possible to use @fontface with Android?  If so can anyone explain weher i'm going wrong with below?

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'BloklettersPotlood';
src: url('fonts/Blokletters-Potlood-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/Blokletters-Potlood-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/Blokletters-Potlood-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/Blokletters-Potlood-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/Blokletters-Potlood-webfont.svg#BloklettersPotlood') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does support @font-face. I'm using the same syntax and it works great (everywhere).
Have you tried to use another font?

Btw. if you are trying to apply your font for any headers, be sure you set `font-weight: normal;` in h1/h2/h3/hx style declaration.